# Can I ask the attributes of a class in a sub-definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables, input

Merry Christmas!

I was trying to generate some code which would make a sort of database using the information provided by the user.
Can I use `input()` method to define my instance variables?

```
class Compound:
def __init__(self, name, state, molecular_mass, concentration, concentration_measure):
    self.nome = name
    self.state = state
    self.mol_mass = molecular_mass
    self.conc = concentration
    self.measure = concentration_measure

def summary(self):
     return ('Your compound is {} it has a state of {} it has a molecular mass of {} g/mol and a concentration of {} and a measure of {}'
             .format(self.name, self.state, self.mol_mass, self.conc, self.measure))

def ask_compounds():
    self.nome = input("Name?")
    self.state = input('Solid or Liquid')
    self.mas_mol = input('Absolute number for molecular weight?')
    self.conc = input('Concentration?')
    self.measure = str(input('In M? In g/ml?'))

ask_compounds()
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. Either `return` the inputted values and initialize a `Compound` class with them:

```
def ask_compounds():
    nome = input("Name?")
    state = input('Solid or Liquid')
    mas_mol = input('Absolute number for molecular weight?')
    conc = input('Concentration?')
    measure = input('In M? In g/ml?')
    return nome, state, mas_mol, conc, measure

inst = Compound(*ask_compounds())
```

or, even better, make `ask_compounds` a `classmethod` that creates instances for you:

```
class Compound:
    def __init__(self, name, state, molecular_mass, concentration, concentration_measure):
        # snipped for brevity

    def summary(self):
         # snipped for brevity

    @classmethod
    def ask_compounds(cls):
        nome = input("Name?")
        state = input('Solid or Liquid')
        mas_mol = input('Absolute number for molecular weight?')
        conc = input('Concentration?')
        measure = input('In M? In g/ml?')
        return cls(nome, state, mas_mol, conc, measure)

inst = Compound.ask_compounds()
```

As an aside, you're using `nome` in `__init__` and `ask_components` but `name` in `summary`, change one of the two to the other.